# Cannot forward stdin to sudo subprocess in Go

Tags: linux, go, process, io

Below is a minimal working example, demonstrating the question.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    //cmd := exec.Command("sudo", "tail", "-10", "/var/log/syslog")
    cmd := exec.Command("cat")
    stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    ForwardStdIn(stdin)
    go ForwardStdOut(stdout)
    go ForwardStdErr(stderr)
    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err == nil {
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    if ee, ok := err.(*exec.ExitError); ok {
        fmt.Println(ee.Error())
        os.Exit(ee.ExitCode())
    } else {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}

func ForwardStdOut(stdout io.ReadCloser) {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()
        _, err := fmt.Fprint(os.Stdout, line+"\n")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}

func ForwardStdErr(stderr io.ReadCloser) {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stderr)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()
        _, err := fmt.Fprint(os.Stderr, line+"\n")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}

func readStdin(ch chan []byte) {
    for {
        buf := make([]byte, 4096)
        n, err := os.Stdin.Read(buf)
        if n == 0 && err == io.EOF {
            close(ch)
            //fmt.Println("stdin closed #1")
            break
        }
        //fmt.Printf("read %v bytes\n", n)
        if n > 0 {
            ch <- buf[:n]
        }
    }
}

func writeStdin(stdin io.WriteCloser, ch chan []byte) {
    for {
        buf, ok := <-ch
        if !ok {
            err := stdin.Close()
            //fmt.Println("stdin closed #2")
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            break
        }
        pos := 0
        for pos < len(buf) {
            n, err := stdin.Write(buf[pos:])
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            //fmt.Printf("wrote %v bytes\n", n)
            pos += n
        }
    }
}

func ForwardStdIn(stdin io.WriteCloser) {
    ch := make(chan []byte, 2)
    go readStdin(ch)
    go writeStdin(stdin, ch)
}
```

If I run this program, then anything I write into stdin appears on stdout.

But if I replace `cat` with `sudo tail -10 /var/log/syslog` then it just does not work. First it asks for my password. I type in the password, press `ENTER`. The debugger shows that the password was sent to the stdin of `sudo`, but nothing else happens. There is no error message, and no further output is produced.

I first thought that maybe `sudo` requires a full featured pty (terminal) to work, but this is not true. I can run `sudo` without a tty this way:

```bash
sudo tail -10 /var/log/syslog </dev/null |& cat
```

and it works fine.

The question is this: Why does the above code work for `cat` but not for `sudo`? How to change this code to make it work with `sudo` (or any other program that uses askpass).

Comment: If I press `ENTER` twice after the password, then sudo writes "Sorry, try again." It looks like it does not receive the data until the second "\n", and then it thinks that the first \n is part of the password. What is happening here?

Comment: `sudo -S tail -10 /var/log/syslog` also works, it seems that the default password reading method requires a terminal; but for some reason, sudo cannot detect that it is not connected to a terminal https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/blob/main/src/tgetpass.c#L141 ???